# Trying to understand super attribute in swift subclasses

Tags: swift, class

I'm learning swift and I'm tryong to understand the use of the super attribute when initializing subclasses

sample code:

```
class Square: NamedShape {
    var sideLength: Double

    init(sideLength: Double, name: String) {
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init(name: name)
        numberOfSides = 4
    }

    func area() ->  Double {
        return sideLength * sideLength
    }

    override func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A square with sides of length \(sideLength)."
    }
}
let test = Square(sideLength: 5.2, name: "my test square")
test.area()
test.simpleDescription()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `super` calls the `init` method of `NamedShape`, the superclass of `Square`. This method is responsible for initializing all of `NamedShape`'s required properties and doing any other setup.

You haven't posted the code for this class, but it looks like this method might set a default value for `numberOfSides` and stores the value of `name`.

The [Swift Initialization docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) provide many more details.

Answer (score 1):

`super` in Swift basically means "the superclass". And what is a superclass? In this case, `NamedShape` is the superclass of `Square`.

And in the superclass, there is an initializer:

```
init(name: String) {
    //code not given so I cannot tell you want is in here
    //You just need to know that there is an initializer.
}
```

And your `Square` class is called the "subclass" of `NamedShape`. In the subclass, you declared an initializer too.

```
init(sideLength: Double, name: String) {
    self.sideLength = sideLength
    super.init(name: name)
    numberOfSides = 4
}
```

In the subclass initializer, you call `super.init`. This is what it means,

> Hey superclass! I want to call your initializer to help me initialize this `Square`, I'll give you the arguments needed - `name`.

And so the superclass initializer does his job and helps you initialize a `Square`.

this is called "initializer delegation".